# How do I change Atom ctrl-tab to not show pane?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, atom-editor

In Sublime when cycling through tabs using `ctrl-tab` it opens and shows the file as I cycle through them. In Atom it shows a pane / list of the recently viewed files. I want to turn this off and just have it cycle through the files and display them as I press `ctrl-tab` like Sublime. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move tabs settings (Settings > Packages > Tabs)
and uncheck 'Display MRU Tab Switching List'

Answer (score 2):

Go to File > Keymap...

Enter in the following code:

```
'body':
  'ctrl-tab': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-tab ^ctrl': 'unset!'
```

This should disable the pane feature completely.

If you want to cycle through the tabs, you press <kbd>CTRL+PAGEDOWN</kbd> for left to right; and <kbd>CTRL+PAGEUP</kbd> from right to left.

If you want to change the keybind entirely, as in you want to use <kbd>CTRL+TAB</kbd> to cycle through the tabs, you can insert this snippet into the Keymap:

```
'body':
  'ctrl-tab': 'pane:show-next-item'
```

Comment: Did not work for me in fact it disabled it completely.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to disable it completely. Having read your question, I was mistaken. I'll try to edit (although I'm not at a computer).